# Extending Angular2 Http provider and handling server

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-http

I followed [this](http://www.adonespitogo.com/articles/angular-2-extending-http-provider/) article to extend the Http provider and created my own custom Http provider. Now I am trying to catch all server exception and depending upon the status code need to take appropriate action.

**http.service.ts:**

```
     @Injectable()
export class HttpService extends Http {

    constructor(backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) {
        let token = localStorage.getItem('auth_token'); // your custom token getter function here
        options.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
        super(backend, options);
    }

    request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        let token = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
        if (typeof url === 'string') { // meaning we have to add the token to the options, not in url
            if (!options) {
                // let's make option object
                options = { headers: new Headers() };
            }
            options.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
        } else {
            // we have to add the token to the url object
            url.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
        }
        return super.request(url, options).catch(this.catchAuthError(this));
    }

    private catchAuthError(self: HttpService) {
        //I want to execute this function whenever there is any error from the server, 
        //but control is not coming here.
        return (res: Response) => {
            console.log("This is from the proxy http", res);
            if (res.status === 401 || res.status === 403) {
                // if not authenticated
                console.log("Do something");
            }
            return Observable.throw(res);
        };
    }
}
```

**Assets.service.ts:**

```
import { HttpService } from './http.service';
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    constructor(private _http: HttpService) {
        login(userName: string, password: string) {
            const headers = new Headers();
            headers.append("Authorization", 'Basic ' + btoa(userName + ":" + password));
            headers.append("Content-Type", 'text/plain');
            const requestUrl = this.loginResource + userName;
            return this._http.get(requestUrl, { headers: headers })
                .map((response: Response) => {
                    let res = response.json();
                    this.token = response.headers.get('token')
                    return res;
                });
        }
    }
}
```

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { HttpService } from './services/http.service';
@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, ...],
    declarations: [...],
    providers: [
        { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
        {
            provide: HttpService,
            useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) => {
                return new HttpService(backend, options);
            },
            deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
        }
    ],

    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})

export class AppModule {
}
```

**EDIT:**
My custom Http provider is not making the xhr calls, instaed even after extending http, it's still invoking the inbuilt http.request.

I created a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/7TuUaXk2dABXDHQlWIAb?p=preview) and the custom Http call is working there, but not in my local code (xhr calls are working but the inbuilt one not the custom). Not sure what exactly is conflicting in the local code.

Answer (score 0):

```
return super.request(url, options).catch(this.catchAuthError(this));
```

should be

```
return super.request(url, options).catch(this.catchAuthError.bind(this));
```

or

```
return super.request(url, options).catch((err) => this.catchAuthError(err));
```

and

```
private catchAuthError (self: HttpService) {
```

should be

```
private catchAuthError (err) {
```

Comment: The service is executing the default http.request() and not the one which I extended. So the line: return super.request(url, options).catch(this.catchAuthError.bind(this)); never gets executed.

Comment: Change `provide: HttpService` to `provide: Http`

Answer (score 0):

Provide your extended class as `useClass` value:

```
{   
    provide : Http,
    useClass:AppHTTPInterceptor,
    deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, AnyOtherService]
},
```

`AnyOtherService` should not depend on `Http`, otherwise it would result in a  cyclic dependency error.